Search Apple Numbers Table where duplicates exist using multiple criteria
How do you perform a Lookup in Apple Numbers using multiple where conditions? Example, I want to know the $ Complete for LOB == Product A, Feature == New Function, and Activity == TaskC. And if % Complete is less than 100%, return Finish Date, otherwise return "completed".



I figured out a way to answer my question. Here is what I've done.

in the Project Plan table, I created a new column (Search - Hidden) that I combined the desired search string

on the Summary slide, I wrote the following LOOKUP string.
LOOKUP(C$1&" Safety "&$A3,'Search (Hidden)','% Complete')


It works as designed.


